# How to check if there is a linear relationship for a logistic regression model

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, logistic

From what I understand logistic regression expects that there is a linear relationship between the log odds of the target and the feature.

> Fourth, logistic regression assumes linearity of independent variables
>   and log odds.  although this analysis does not require the dependent
>   and independent variables to be related linearly, it requires that the
>   independent variables are linearly related to the log odds.

Source: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/

However logistic regression also allows for a feature to be binary besides numeric if I am correct (could not find anything on this but it is allowed in linear regression). How would one check if the independent variables are linearly related to the log odds of the target if the independent variables are binary?

Answer (score 1):

Independent variable being binary instead of numeric doesn't change anything. Logistic regression's *assumption* is still valid, because in the end it is the assumption of the model, irrelavant to the fact that it is correct or not.

Comment: Is there any way of checking this assumption, preferably in R?